# Почему выдает ошибку при нажатии на mat-slide-toggle

Tags: angular, angular2, angular4, angular10

Вот мой код с mat-slide-toggle

```
 <tr *ngFor="let user of clients | async">
                <td>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</td>
                <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                <td><mat-slide-toggle (change)="changeUserStatus(user)" [checked]="user.isBlocked" ></mat-slide-toggle></td>
                <td>
                    <a class="listEditButton" (click)="editUser(user.id)"><img class="listEditImg" src="../../../../assets/edit.png"/></a>
                    <a class="listDeleteButton" (click)="deleteUser(user.id)"><img class="listDeleteImg" src="../../../../assets/delete.png"/></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

[image: Функция которую я вызываю]

[image: Модель пользователя]

[image: Ошибка которую я получаю при нажатии на toggle]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55588643/4711135

Comment: @AlexanderChernin к сожалению не сработало

Comment: `user = Object.assign({}, user, {isBlocked: !user.isBlocked});`?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin  return this.store$.dispatch(new EditUser(Object.assign({}, user, {isBlocked: !user.isBlocked})));

Comment: Должно работать. Какая ошибка?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin точно такая же как и раньше

Comment: а если так: `let blocked  = user.isBlocked; ... EditUser(Object.assign({}, user, {isBlocked: !blocked}...`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin changeUserStatus(user: UserProfile){
   
    let blocked = user.isBlocked;
    return this.store$.dispatch(new EditUser(Object.assign({}, user, {isBlocked: !blocked})));
  }

Comment: Вот так сейчас выглядит функция , ошибки нет,

Comment: Правда свое назначение она не выполняет, ну это наверно где то у меня ошибка, но вообще хз